# Restcomm Web Trigger returns HTTP 401

Tags: sip-server, mobicents, restcomm

I'm trying to use Web Trigger in a RVD project, but when I do the HTTP call this error appears: **Error 401 running REST GET request: Unauthorized**

After some minutes under debug, I've noticed RvdController.java is trying to access the hardcoded path *"/restcomm/2012-04-24/Accounts.json/" + apiUsername*, the error occurs at this line.
Aparently, the string *"2012-04-24"* is also a preconfigured value at *< api-version >* tag, in *restcomm.war/WEB-INF/conf/restcomm.xml*.

This is the URL I used to make the HTTP GET:
http://localhost:8080/restcomm-rvd/services/apps/testapp/start?from=client:alice&to=client:bob&token=test

Am I missing something? I would like to participate next week TADHack and this resource is important on my project.

Thank you in advance!
Gui.

```
20:06:06,851 ERROR [org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.rvd.http.resources.RvdController] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.rvd.restcomm.RestcommClient$RestcommClientException: Error 401 running REST GET request: Unauthorized - Response body: <html><head><title>JBoss Web/7.2.0.Final - JBWEB000064: Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 401 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>JBWEB000309: type</b> JBWEB000067: Status report</p><p><b>JBWEB000068: message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>JBWEB000069: description</b> <u>JBWEB000121: This request requires HTTP authentication.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBoss Web/7.2.0.Final</h3></body></html>: org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.rvd.restcomm.RestcommClient$RestcommClientException: Error 401 running REST GET request: Unauthorized - Response body: <html><head><title>JBoss Web/7.2.0.Final - JBWEB000064: Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 401 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>JBWEB000309: type</b> JBWEB000067: Status report</p><p><b>JBWEB000068: message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>JBWEB000069: description</b> <u>JBWEB000121: This request requires HTTP authentication.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBoss Web/7.2.0.Final</h3></body></html>
    at org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.rvd.restcomm.RestcommClient$Request.done(RestcommClient.java:90) [classes:]
    at org.mobicents.servlet.restcomm.rvd.http.resources.RvdController.executeAction(RvdController.java:374) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350) [jersey-server-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416) [jersey-servlet-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538) [jersey-servlet-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716) [jersey-servlet-1.13.jar:1.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final.jar:1.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the credentials for accessing Restcomm REST API in the RVD 'IDE Settings'. In order to do that:

- Start your project in RVD and click on the top right gear icon (the one that when hovering over it says 'IDE Settings'). A 'Restcomm API' settings dialog should appear.
- Fill in the Username and Password fields. Enter a username and password of a restcomm user that can access restcomm REST api. The username/password combination used for logging into RVD or Restcomm Administration should do.
- You can leave the 'host' and 'port' fields empty.

RVD's WebTrigger relies on the Restcomm REST API in order to start the application. That's why you need to enter the credentials there.

Comment: Thank you so much @otsakir ! Following your instructions, Web Trigger is working good now. There is another issue about the collect verb, seems to not get the digits from the sip client, but i will run a few more tests and collect info to post a new question soon.